# How to access to a React Application from an external network?

Tags: reactjs, networking

I am running a React application on a Windows Server. I can access to it from browser using both the local machine and another pc on the same local network, but not from an external network.

I've tried both the development mode, `ip:3000`, and production mode with `ip:5000`.

Now I am wondering if it's a networking issue or I need to do something in my React code.
I didn't find anything in the documentation.

What do you do to make available an application to others?

Thanks.

Comment: can you explain Lil more?. what is `ip` also which server you using

Answer (score 0):

You can setup firebase to you react app and deploy you application on firebase console.

- Login in firebase using google account
- Create project and app
- Complete firebase setup to the project
- Create Build and Deploy app on firebase.

Follow below link for steps :

https://medium.com/@aleemuddin13/how-to-host-static-website-on-firebase-hosting-for-free-9de8917bebf2

https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-with-firebase-hosting-98063c5bf425

Firebase project has free subdomains on the web.app and firebaseapp.com domains. You can access via these links.